# Does the Theorem of Stone Weierstrass imply that every function is part of a vector space?

Tags: analysis

Weierstrass Approximation Theorem. Suppose  f  is a continuous real-valued function defined on the real interval [a, b]. For every ε > 0, there exists a polynomial p such that for all x in [a, b], we have | f (x) − p(x)| < ε, or equivalently, the supremum norm || f  − p|| < ε.

Does that mean that every continuous real valued function is always a part of a vector space and does the polynomial p is a element of that space?

Comment: The real-valued continuous functions form a vector space, and the set of all polynomials is a linear subspace. The Stone-Weierstrass theorem implies that the space of polynomials is dense in the continuous functions, when equipped with the supremum norm.

Comment: ok. can you answer so i can accept your answer?

Comment: But the facts that the continuous functions form a vector space and the polynomials a subspace don't come from the Weierstrass theorem, they form part of the background for the theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real-valued continuous functions form a vector space, and the set of all polynomials is a linear subspace. The Stone-Weierstrass theorem implies that the space of polynomials is dense in the continuous functions, when equipped with the supremum norm.